# How define AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION in oracle?

Tags: oracle

How to define the `autonomous pragma` for `error logging` in oracle with the help of procedure.My table structure is like below.

```
  CREATE TABLE error_logs (
      id             NUMBER(10)     NOT NULL,
      log_timestamp  TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL,
      error_message  VARCHAR2(4000),
      CONSTRAINT error_logs_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
              );

  CREATE SEQUENCE error_logs_seq
   start with 1
   nocycle
   nocache;
```

i  tried below code for my requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_errors (p_error_message  IN  VARCHAR2) AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO error_logs (id, log_timestamp, error_message)
  VALUES (error_logs_seq.NEXTVAL, SYSTIMESTAMP, p_error_message);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Looks ok, what is the problem?

Comment: what is the error.